# Why does Wolframalpha think that this sum converges?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, summation

Looking at the sum:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\tan\left(\frac\pi{2^n}\right)$$

I'd say that it does not converge, because for $n=1$ the tangent $\tan\left(\frac\pi 2\right)$ should be undefined. But Wolframlpha thinks that the sum [converges somewhere around $1.63312×10^{16}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_(n%3D1)%5Einfinity+tan(pi%2F2%5En)).

What am I missing?

Comment: Does wolframalpha use numeric method for determining this? In that case it's correct because $\pi/2$ rounds to something that's only almost $\pi/2$ and $\tan$ of that is probably a finite number. Note that it's "obvious" that the sum $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \tan(\pi/2^n)$ converges.

Comment: Because machines can't represent irrational number such as $pi/2$. So you get some "large number" instead.

Comment: It seems like a bug. You should report it.

Comment: You are right. And W|A knows in principle that that tangent is infinite. But  likely at this point for some reason an approximation of $\pi/2$ is used and this explains it.

Comment: This is not a question about mathematics but rather a question about using some software.

Comment: @A.S. : WolframAlpha and Wolfram Mathematica represent the number $\pi/2$ exactly as precisely as you do, as "$\pi/2$".  Many CASs represent irrationals symbolically.

Comment: @Eric not when W|A is trying to evaluate an infinite series which it can't sum up symbolically - as evidenced by the OP. My original comment is indeed technically incorrect, but it still points to the core of the problem.

Comment: Building on the answer below by @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla : Initially for me WA reports "By the comparison test, the series converges", and then about 5 seconds later this *switches* to saying "By the ratio test, the series converges".

Comment: It is a bit hard to say whether $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\tan\left(\frac\pi{2^n}\right)$ converges or diverges because clearly the terms tend to zero quickly enough, and the problem is that the first term is not even properly defined.

Comment: Also since this is midterm time,  obligatory "use your common sense" as the submitter did. Double check your answer makes sense before you move on.

Comment: I don't know what Wolfram Alpha does, but Mathematica's `Sum` just returns that series unevaluated. `NSum`, however, gives this large number as result.

Comment: It's sad that many people still think Wolfram Alpha is **supposed** to be reliable. Many times, whenever mathematical errors are reported, the underlying algorithms are not fixed at all but they simply fix the output on a case by case basis, and so of course they still get infinitely many cases wrong. I do **not** recommend reporting bugs because students tend to use Wolfram Alpha blindly and it doesn't help them one bit.

Comment: I don't get it:  Is the math.SE community made up of people who never used a computer?  This is so obviously a floating-point precision problem, combined with a software bug:  Mathematica uses symbols, so there's no reason its  tan function shouldn't catch $\pi/2$ and spit out "infinity" right then and there.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

For floating point numbers stored in IEEE double precision format, the significant has $53$ bit of accuracy. The most significant bit is implied and is always one. Only $52$ bits are actually stored.

Since $1 \le \frac{\pi}{2} < 2$, among those numbers representable by IEEE,
the closest number to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ is
$$\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)_{fp} \stackrel{def}{=} 2^{-52}\left\lfloor \frac{\pi}{2} \times 2^{52}\right\rfloor$$

Numerically, we have $$\frac{\pi}{2} - \left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)_{fp} \approx 6.1232339957\times 10^{-17}$$

Since for $\theta \approx \frac{\pi}{2}$, $\displaystyle\;\tan\theta \approx \frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2} - \theta}$, we have

$$\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)_{fp}
\approx \frac{1}{6.1232339957\times 10^{-17}}
\approx 1.6331239353 \times 10^{16}$$

This is approximately the number you observed.

Comment: It's funny and sad the same time that W|A represents real numbers in IEEE 754 format :-X

Comment: And to be clear, if this is the result of the first term, then it completely overwhelms the rest of the series, because from $n = 2$ to infinity the sum is only about $1.8$.

Comment: @imanoob - do you have an alternative idea for representing numbers in the finite limitations of a computer that allows for reasonable computations such as this?

Comment: Preface: I do not really understand how W|A and Mathematica deal with symbolic vs. floating point representations. .....That said,  your answer does not seem to explain why $\tan{(\pi/2)}=ComplexInfinity$ but $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \tan \frac{\pi}{2^n}$ does not evaluate to ComplexInfinity.

Comment: @mrc, Simple, if an expression is complicated enough and WA don't know how to compute it symbolically, then it switch to compute it numerically. The only thing one should complain is WA didn't notice the numerical result looks bogus and issue some warnings...

Comment: Hmmm, I think it's fair to complain that WA should notice that in a sum of nonnegative terms in which one term is infinite, the whole sum is infinite.

Comment: @mrc: it would be fair to complain that WA should notice this in a _finite_ sum. And indeed [it does](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1678366/11107). Complaining that it should notice this in any infinite sum would be [less fair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem), actually.

Comment: Good point :) I am unfair.

Comment: @mrc it figures it out sometimes, try and sum 1/n from 0 to inf. (https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_%28n%3D0%29^inf+1%2F%28n%29) (sum does not exist due to singularity at 1 or more evaluation points) a difference here I guess is that 1/n from 1 to inf. diverges

Comment: I know nothing about computers, but surely the system should be able to recognize that $\tan$ is undefined for certain arguments.

Answer (score 25):

Possible explication: Wolfram Alpha applies some convergence test and says "is convergent". But as does not know any closed form, does a numerical approximation.

EDIT: interesting phenomenon: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_(n%3D1)%5E7000+tan(pi%2F2%5En). Try and wait a bit.

Comment: Nice party trick!

Comment: You don't need to sum to 7000.  https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_(n%3D1)%5E1+tan(pi%2F2%5En) shows that W|A "knows" it's infinite at 1.

Comment: @Taemyr, the interesting bit is that during some seconds the answer is $1.63312×10^{16}$.

Comment: Hmm, I missed that first time round.

Comment: What the devil is $\widetilde \infty$?

Comment: @Steven: Infiñity, of course.

Comment: I like math humor.

Comment: @StevenGregory: That symbol "is complex infinity" (per fine print on the WA result), i.e.,point at infinity in the complex plane.

Comment: This "switch" also happens for the OP's link in regards to the test that WA says shows convergence. (!)

Answer (score 6):

Computing

> tan(pi/2)

with Python or Matlab yields $1.633123935319537\mathrm{e}{+}16$. Hence, this is just a result of rounding errors (the remaining terms in the sum are quite small).

Comment: I wonder how the internal calculation works... Is there any way we might be able to look at the relevant code segment?

Comment: @Stefan: This is more related to floating-point arithmetic than to the actual source code of Python/Matlab. `pi/2` is just the floating-point number nearest to $\pi/2$ and `tan(pi/2)` is an approximation of its tangent. Since $\pi/2 \ne$`pi/2`, `tan(pi/2)` is quite large.

Comment: However computing tan(pi/2) with W|A gives infinity.  https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=tan(pi%2F2)

Comment: The sum of the first $6000$ terms [https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_(n%3D1)%5E6000+tan(pi%2F2%5En)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_(n%3D1)%5E6000+tan(pi%2F2%5En)) gives an infinite number but the sum of the first $7000$ does not even though the difference should only be be about $2 \times 10^{-1806}$.